# Use different list values in order to do the same sum with each

Tags: python

Please help, I need to have a moving value in my code based upon a list!
I have a list, the list is as follows:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 10]
```

I have a part of my code which uses this list in order to do a sum, this is as follows:

```
val = my_list[0]+1
ans = val*9
```

What I want is to have val be replaced by each of the numbers in my_list i.e. the first time it would be 1x9 and then the next 2x9. However, I cannot find anywhere how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
val = my_list[x]
val += 1
ans = val * 9
x += 1
```

this way you can just run your code, then add 1 to x
move the x += 1 line to whereever you want

Answer (score 0):

What you want is vectorization - for which you can use the numpy package:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 10] 
my_np_list = np.array(my_list)

ans = 9 * my_np_list 
# vectorization applies to each element of my_np_list in parallel 
# the `9 *` calculation.
## ans contains:
## array([ 9, 18, 18, 27, 45, 54, 63, 63, 81, 90])

## you can sum accross ans by the .sum() method
ans.sum() ## 468
```

It is as if you do:

```
ans = []
for x in my_list:
    ans.append(9 * x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your ans a list?

Do "(x+1)*9" for each elements?

```
ans = [(x+1)*9 for x in my_list]
```